# how to restore vm instance from terminated state ?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I halted the linux vm instances for couple of days. I dont see any options to turn it back on. I hit reboot and it pops the error here is detailed log
"RESOURCE_NOT_READY: The resource 'projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-a/instances/myinstance' is not ready"
I still see the disk for instance there and it marks active. Is there any way to reactivate the instance ? 
thanks

Comment: Did you 'halt' or 'shutdown' the instance from inside a guest OS?

Answer (score 5):

Instances in a "TERMINATED" state cannot be restarted. If your instance is in this state, the only option is to delete the instance. Any data on scratch disks is gone.

Persistent Disks are independent of instances. If your disk is a Persistent Disk, you can create a new instance with the disk attached and continue using the disk.

Comment: What sense does it make for a "terminated" instance not being able to be restarted? Since the only option is to delete it, why don't google guys simply call it "deleted" and tell us that when you `sudo shutdown -h now` from in the instance, you are actually "deleting" the instance?

Comment: The "terminated" state is a way to keep the information about an instance available even after the instance has stopped. There are many cases where the guest OS halts, but it isn't user initiated. For example: a kernel module might crash the kernel. In that situation you really want the serial console output to remain available even though the underlying instance is gone.

Comment: Thank you Brian, that make sense, and reasonable. So is there no way to temporarily stop an instance and start it later?

Comment: There isn't a way to pause a running instance. However, when you create an instance, if you uncheck "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" on the web UI, the disk lives independently of the instance. You can delete the instance and always boot a new instance from the same disk. It's as if a physical machine disappeared whenever it was turned off. You can also choose the instance settings each time you create it to boot up with more or fewer CPUs, RAM, etc.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Brian. I'll look it as the (vogue)way to do "shutdown-reboot" thing on GCE.

Comment: I believe that this answer is no longer entirely accurate. I am able to do `gcloud compute instances start my-terminated-instance` in cases that I have manually stopped the instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible!

Please have a look at the instances.start API call https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.start

Answer (score 0):

as of 2019-03-22, a machine in the state of "terminated", use can choose to either "start" or "delete" it.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/instance-life-cycle