# Getting Status Terminated Error While Moving Google Compute Engine VM on Google Cloud Platform To Another Zone

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

When I try to move the VM with the following command

```
gcloud compute instances move neomoment-demo-01 \
    --zone us-east1-b --destination-zone europe-north1-a
```

It gives me this.

> Moving gce instance neomoment-demo-01...failed. ERROR:
>   (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instance cannot be moved while in
>   state: TERMINATED

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103294/how-to-restore-vm-instance-from-terminated-state) (see answer near the bottom starting "This is now possible!"). I think you need to move your VM out of terminated state before you retry the move.

Comment: Start the instance and try again.